# Pushbutton is not being responsive

Tags: python, inheritance, pyqt5, qpushbutton

i'm pretty new to python and PyQt5.

My goal is to use a "Push Button" to move to the next widget in the "Stacked Layout". However, it's not being responsive, and it appears that it won't enter the function in order to move on to the next widget.

I have no idea wether its the inheritance i've messed up on, or something else. Any guidance is really appreciated. Thank you!

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Menu(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def setupUI(self, Main):

        Main.setObjectName("Main")
        Main.setFixedSize(900, 500)

        self.width = 900
        self.height = 500

        self.setFixedSize(self.width, self.height)


        self.menu = QtWidgets.QStackedLayout()

        self.welcomeMenu = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.mainMenu = QtWidgets.QWidget()

        self.welcomeUi()
        self.menuUi()

        self.menu.addWidget(self.welcomeMenu)
        self.menu.addWidget(self.mainMenu)

    def welcomeUi(self):

        #Button for entering portal
        self.entrBtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.welcomeMenu)
        self.entrBtn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(25,150,200,50))
        self.entrBtn.setText("To the menu screen!")

        #Having welcome text
        self.welcomeText = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.welcomeMenu)
        self.welcomeText.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 120, 480, 200))
        self.welcomeText.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeading|QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft|QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
        self.welcomeText.setText("Welcome!")

    def menuUi(self):
        self.text = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.mainMenu)
        self.text.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 120, 480, 200))
        self.text.setText("test")


class Main(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Menu):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Main, self).__init__()
        self.setupUI(self)
        self.entrBtn.clicked.connect(self.menuWindow)

    def menuWindow(self):
        self.menu.setCurrentWidget(self.mainMenu)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    m = Main()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is simple: QLabel is on top of the button so it will block all mouse events. The simple solution is to put QPushButton on QLabel using raise_():

```
# ...
self.welcomeText.setText("Welcome!")

self.entrBtn.raise_()
```

But that solves the superficial problem, you have other bigger problem: You should not inherit from 2 QWidget, also the Main is not shown. It is better to rewrite the code as follows:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.welcomeMenu = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.mainMenu = QtWidgets.QWidget()

        self.fill_welcomeUi()
        self.fill_menuUi()

        self.stacked_lay = QtWidgets.QStackedLayout()

        self.stacked_lay.addWidget(self.welcomeMenu)
        self.stacked_lay.addWidget(self.mainMenu)

        central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)
        central_widget.setLayout(self.stacked_lay)

        self.entrBtn.clicked.connect(self.menuWindow)

        self.resize(640, 480)

    def menuWindow(self):
        self.stacked_lay.setCurrentWidget(self.mainMenu)

    def fill_welcomeUi(self):

        #Button for entering portal
        self.entrBtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.welcomeMenu)
        self.entrBtn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(25,150,200,50))
        self.entrBtn.setText("To the menu screen!")

        #Having welcome text
        self.welcomeText = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.welcomeMenu)
        self.welcomeText.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 120, 480, 200))
        self.welcomeText.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeading|QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft|QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
        self.welcomeText.setText("Welcome!")

        self.entrBtn.raise_()

    def fill_menuUi(self):
        self.text = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.mainMenu)
        self.text.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 120, 480, 200))
        self.text.setText("test")



if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    m = MainWindow()
    m.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```